# Trouble logging in to Pinterest with ruby mechanize

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, mechanize, pinterest

I am trying to build a simple crawler that can login to Pinterest and pin a few things to my board.

The first step of this is successfully login. I read through the documentation and it seems like this should work but it doesn't.

When I run the code I expect it to print out a title like "Mary... is mary... on Pinterest"

But instead the title of the page is "Pinterest-The Visual Discovery Tool"

I think there's something wrong with my script.

```
require 'rubygems'                                                                 
require 'mechanize'                                                                
require 'pry'                                                                      

a = Mechanize.new                                                                  
a.get('https://www.pinterest.com/login/') do |page|                                
  form = page.forms.first                                                          
  form.fields[0].value = "m...@gmail.com"                                 
  form.fields[1].value = "some_password"                                         
  new_page  = form.submit                                                          
  puts new_page.title                                                              
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that mechanize has no capability of executing javascript and if the page depends on javascript, it may not load correctly. Although I only did a light read through of the source, it looks like it is very dependent on javascript and therefore can't be crawled effectively with mechanize.

Another option might be to use a headless browser like [watir](http://watir.com/) or [selenium](http://selenium.rubyforge.org/).